# Extract String value from array formula - Excel

Tags: arrays, string, excel, match

I'm trying to find a way to extract a string from an array that has been created using an array function.

As a quick example, here is what I'm working with:

I've got a database with 3 columsn, "Place", "Type", and "ID"

```
  A        B       C
Place     Type     ID
Toronto   apple 
Calgary   pear  
Toronto   pear  
Cornwall  apple 
Brockville banana   
Calgary     apple   
Bellville   pear    
Oakville    pear    
Brockville  banana  
Cornwall    apple   
Bellville   strawberry  
Sarnia      strawberry  
Quebec City mango   
Montreal    lime    
Montreal    lemon   

  E        F       G
Place     Type     ID
Toronto   apple   ABC 1111
Calgary   pear    ABC 1112
Toronto   pear    ABC 1113
Cornwall  apple   ABC 1114
Brockville banana ABC 1115
Calgary     apple ABC 1116
Bellville   pear  ABC 1117
Oakville    pear  ABC 1118
```

I've got another list that is a subset of the items on this list, but has the ID section filled in. The IDs are formatted like so "ABC 1234".

When I had the IDs as numbers, the formula was simple.

```
{=max(if(a1=E:E,if(b1=F:F,G:G,0),0))}
```

This would return the value in G that as long as E and F matched the row I was analyzing. However I'm unsure what to use when the value being assigned is a string.

From my understanding, the reason the max works, is because the array is populated in the following way:

For the case of "Toronto" "Pear", the array would be {0,0,0,1113,0,0,0,0}, and choosing the max from the array returns the correct value of 1113.

**My question is:**

**How do I select the string from the following array.**

```
{0,0,0,ABC 1113,0,0,0,0}
```

PS. Eventually I'll be coding it so it handles multiple matches and returns the corresponding value, (as in, 3rd match, returns the 3rd ID) however I think I know how to do that already, provided I figure this step out.

Comment: Have you tried only grabbing the subst or the right of that section of the array?  Like, if you know the ID is a 4 digit number, grab =right([cell],4)  Rather than grabbing the entire string.

Comment: Whelp - literally seconds after posting this I went back to my example and solved the problem myself. Rather than setting the value using the IF statement, I set the row corresponding to that match and indexed on it. The solution is below.

    {=index(G:G,max(if(a1=E:E,if(b1=F:F,row(G:G),0),0)))}

I can't answer the question because I don't have a high enough reputation, but I've confirmed that this works.

Comment: It says I have to wait 8 hours. Probably so I can't just post a question and post the answer over and over to boost my rating.

Comment: @user3772884 it's alredy more than 8 hours since you posted the question..